# progressive input placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm curious how to implement progressive/dynamic placeholder like the below example in CSS/Javascript.
[image]

PS. I know we need to show some kind of work/effort before posting to SO. but I'm kinda confuse what to search to get relevant information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function:

```js
var finalPlaceholderText = "foo bar bazaazz";
var input = document.getElementById('idOfTextBox');
var len = finalPlaceholderText.length;
var timerID;
var counter = 0;

if (counter <= len) {
  timerID = setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    typewriter(counter)
  }, 100);
}

function typewriter(i) {
  input.placeholder = finalPlaceholderText.substring(0, i);
  if (i === len) {
    counter = 0;
    //comment out below if you want it to stop
    //clearInterval(timerID)
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="idOfTextBox" placeholder="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `<input placeholder=""` attribute using `setTimeout` or `setInterval` for an animation loop.

A simpler version just spams a bunch of future updates using `setTimeout` instead of an animation loop as I think it's simpler - though this approach does not scale.

```
var finalPlaceholderText = "foo bar baz";
var input = document.getElementById( 'idOfTextBox' );    

var placeholderIndex = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < finalPlaceholderText.length; i++ ) {

    setTimeout( 
        function( length ) {
            input.placeholder = finalPlaceholderText.substring( 0, i );
        }
    , i * 500, i );
}
```

Note you need to pass `length` (`i`) as a parameter into the `setTimeout` callback because JavaScript's closures will use the *last* value after the `for` loop finishes instead of the value used when `setTimeout` was called each time.

Using a `setTimeout`-loop, it would look like this (note the lack of a `for` loop):

```
var finalPlaceholderText = "foo bar baz";
var input = document.getElementById( 'idOfTextBox' );

function incrementPlaceholderText( i ) {
    input.placeholder = finalPlaceholderText.substring( 0, i );

    if( i < finalPlaceholderText.length ) {
        setTimeout( incrementPlaceholderText, 500, i + 1 );
    }
}

incrementPlaceholderText( 0 );
```

Or more generally (in a way that supports multiple input elements and different placeholder texts):

```
function incrementPlaceholderText( input, finalText, i ) {
    input.placeholder = finalText.substring( 0, i );

    if( i < finalText.length ) {
        setTimeout( incrementPlaceholderText, 500, input, finalText, i + 1 );
    }
}

incrementPlaceholderText( document.getElementById( 'idOfTextBox1' ), "foo bar baz", 0 );
incrementPlaceholderText( document.getElementById( 'idOfTextBox2' ), "foo bar baz qux", 0 );
```

Comment: It should be `input.placeholder`.

Comment: @SachiTekina Good catch! I wasn't thinking :) I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this snippet will be useful. Have added comments for clarification

```js
//create a variable. This will be used to create substring
var initialChar = 0;
//get the element and placeholder
let getElement = document.getElementById('inputElem');
let getPlaceHolderText = getElement.getAttribute('placeholder');
//create IIFE and this will be called as long as placeholder is not 
//completly created
(function setPlaceholder() {
  //settime out function to input one text at a time
  let clearNow = setTimeout(function() {
    // increase the count
    initialChar++;
    //create a substring and set this value as placeholder
    let getChar = getPlaceHolderText.substring(0, initialChar);
    getElement.setAttribute('placeholder', getChar + '|')
    // when the variable value and length of string
    // is equal it mean all the placeholder text has been created
    // if not equal then add next character to placeholder
    if (initialChar !== getPlaceHolderText.length) {
      // calling the IIFE
      setPlaceholder()
    } else {
      // equal so remove the pipe(pipe to create cursor effect)
      getElement.setAttribute('placeholder', getElement.getAttribute('placeholder').slice(0, -1));
      clearTimeout(clearNow);
    }
  }, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 150)) // any random number
}())
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Add you text here" id="inputElem">
```

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the sources found out that there's an awesome library already built for this.

https://github.com/chinchang/superplaceholder.js